# how to get last_date balance record when we select DATA by date_range

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

for example:

If I apply date_range of '16-May-2019' for know the balance_Column_Record,
then DataGridview should show '15-May-2019's Last balance record even though 15-May-2019 may have many records but just show the last record.

so the first line of the Grid show >> Opening Balance   '5000'
then the applied data show the desired output

I got the following output, but i want to show the output with previous one balance_amount of just before the applied date_range selected

```
Date            Desc          Dr    Cr  Balance
16-May-19   Service loans    5000   0   5000
17-May-19   Service expanse  3000   0   8000
18-May-19   Loan Deduction   2000   0   10000
19-May-19   Bike Loan         0    5000 5000
20-May-19   Office Expanse    0    2000 3000
21-May-19   Lunch Expanse    8000   0   11000
```

I expecting the output like this,

```
Date                Desc    Dr      Cr      Balance
15-May-19   Balance  >>>    -       -       8000
16-May-19   Service loans   5000    0       13000
17-May-19   Service expanse 3000    0       16000
18-May-19   Loan Deduction  2000    0       18000
19-May-19   Bike Loan          0    5000    13000
20-May-19   Office Expanse     0    2000    11000
21-May-19   Lunch Expanse   8000     0      19000
```

Comment: You need to order by date and take last item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help...

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  [Date] DATE,
  [Desc] VARCHAR(100),
  DR DECIMAL(18,2),
  CR DECIMAL(18,2),
  Balance DECIMAL(18,2)
)
INSERT INTO @Temp(Date,[Desc],DR,CR,Balance) VALUES ('15-May-19','Service loans',1000,0,1000)
INSERT INTO @Temp(Date,[Desc],DR,CR,Balance) VALUES ('15-May-19','Service loans',2000,0,3000)
INSERT INTO @Temp(Date,[Desc],DR,CR,Balance) VALUES ('16-May-19','Service loans',5000,0,8000)
INSERT INTO @Temp(Date,[Desc],DR,CR,Balance) VALUES ('17-May-19','Service loans',3000,0,11000)
INSERT INTO @Temp(Date,[Desc],DR,CR,Balance) VALUES ('18-May-19','Service loans',0,1000,10000)


DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '16-May-19'
DECLARE @ToDate DATE = '18-May-19'

;WITH Lastbalance
AS(
SELECT TOP(1) Date,'Balance  >>>' [Desc],'--'DR,'--'CR,Balance
FROM @Temp
WHERE Date =  dateadd(day,-1, cast(@FromDate as date))
ORDER BY Id DESC 
)
SELECT * FROM Lastbalance
UNION
SELECT Date,[Desc],CAST(DR as VARCHAR(10)) DR,CAST(CR as VARCHAR(10)) CR,Balance
FROM @Temp
WHERE Date >= @FromDate AND Date <= @ToDate
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196494/discussion-on-answer-by-khairul-alam-how-to-get-last-date-balance-record-when-we).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(dr - cr) over (order by date) as balance
      from t
     ) t
where date >= '2019-05-15';
```

In other words, calculate the balance in a subquery.  Then do the filtering in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

What type of grid are you using? A DataGridview? You could write one query for the previous balance and insert one grid row for that result then the remaining grid rows with the applied data.

```
DataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: datagridview in c#